# Qt and Linux shell command execution

Tags: linux, qt, shell, opencv, command

Via Qt I'm trying to run an Opencv with the Linux shell.
To be more precise: when I run via shell this command `prova /home/root/neo.jpg` it works correctly and give me the expected results.

When i run the same command via Qt with QProcess it doesn't work, don't give me the result. For testing I've tried to run a simple `ifconfig` and works correctly. This is my code:

```
#include "mostradialog.h"
#include "ui_mostradialog.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QString>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

QString program;

mostraDialog::mostraDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::mostraDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QString nome_foto = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Carica Immagine","/home/root");
    program = "prova "+nome_foto;
    QPixmap pix(nome_foto);
    int w = ui->label_mostra->width();
    int h = ui->label_mostra->height();

    ui->label_mostra->setPixmap(pix.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));




}

mostraDialog::~mostraDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void mostraDialog::on_pushButton_elabora_clicked()
{


    //QString program = "prova /home/root/"+nome_foto;
    QStringList arguments;

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);
    show();
    myProcess->waitForFinished();
    QString strOut = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    ui->label_result->setText(strOut);
    qDebug() << program;
    qDebug() << strOut;

};
```

N.B. the string command format it's correct, I've seen it with `qDebug()`.

Comment: Never post code as an image, always as plain text (formatted using the code formatting button in the editor here). Also doesn't the fact that QProcess requires a _program_ and _arguments_ give you a hint? Haven't you looked at examples?

Comment: sorry, this is the code, i've edited the question

Comment: `program` should contain `prova`, and `arguments` should contain `/path_to_image`. Really, read the doc

Comment: Now i try it. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Thank you so much guys, it works ! The problem now is that the arguments input when i load a new image is added to the previously. In other words, for the first image that i load i have program="prova" and arguments="/home/root/neo.jpg"...when i take a second image to elaborate, arguments is " /home/root/neo.jpg;/home/root/image2.jpg"...and so i don't have te correct result...how can i fix this ?